# How to pass URL parameter to controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass a URL parameter to the controller. On the below URL, I need to pass the **ID** parameter to the controller.

http://localhost/branch/more.php?id=20

Pass the **ID** URL parameter to the controller that I have given below.

```
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("message.php?id=").then(function (response) {
  $scope.myData = response.data.message;
  });
```

So, the **message.php?id=Parameter ID Here** must be like this.

Comment: why answer is remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject **`$routeParams`** in your controller like

```
 app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope,$http,$routeParams) {
 var routeID = $routeParams.id;
 $http.get("message.php?id="+routeID).then(function (response)
```

Comment: why answer is remove?

Comment: After I add the **$routeParams** and  **var routeID = $routeParams.id;** the entire app stoped working.

Comment: I checked the **Network** in Mozilla Developer tools and it's not fetching any result from the **message.php**.

Comment: but this is how you get the id from the routerparams

Comment: The thing is, While I remove the **$routeParams** and **var routeID = $routeParams.id;** the app goes work again. Do I need to add anything in the app in order to workout the $routeParams?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134988/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-muhsin-mohamed-pc).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the id like this you can still access it.

```
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var msgId = "20";
  $http.get("message.php?id=" + msgId).then(function (response) {
  $scope.myData = response.data.message;
  });
```